# Ratio Calculation in Linear Programming?

Tags: linear-programming, ratio, constraints

i struggle a bit with ratio and fraction calculations, so im just looking for some explanation for dummies of this one.

in linear programming, i have a ratio constraint of 6:5, of product A to product B.

The proper way, i believe, to insert this into a linear program is:
5A - 6B >= 0

that is, 5XA - 5XB, must be greater or equal to zero for constraint of 6:5 to be sufficed.

first of all, is this correct?
and if so, can someone try to explain to me how this works? , ie how does flipping the ratio (6:5 , A to b, becomes 5xa - 6xb) cancel the other out and equate to zero or great when constraint is met?

a written example with calculation should help me visualize this, just absolutely struggling to get my head around it.

thanks guys! any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Correct
Example (value of a =60, b=50)
Ratio A:b
          6:5
It is looking for value not ratio
So it is must reverse
Ratio(value) - ratio(value)
               5(a) - 6(b)
           5.(60) - 6.(50) = 300-300 =0
              (60) :     (50) simplify
Value         6 :         5

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).